# Can't resolve include_path issues in CakePHP 2.x

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a CakePHP install that won't resolve paths correctly using include_path.

Here's an example of an error from the PHP log.

```
PHP Warning:  include(\website\cakephp\lib\Cake\Utility\Debugger.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\website\cakephp\lib\Cake\Core\App.php on line 545
PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '\website\cakephp\lib\Cake\Utility\Debugger.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;d:\website') in D:\website\cakephp\lib\Cake\Core\App.php on line 545
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Debugger' not found in D:\website\cakephp\lib\Cake\Error\ErrorHandler.php on line 223
```

My website is installed on drive `D:` but all calls to `App::uses` resolve to paths where the drive letter has been removed.

I've specified `include_path = ".;D:\website"` in the `php.ini` file.

Not sure what else can be done to resolve this issue.

**EDIT:**

If I change the input_path to `.;D:\` then includes start working correctly.

I'm thinking there is something wrong with how my `index.php` configures paths.

Comment: what server are you using? Xampp? Wamp? or pure Apache/Ngix?

Comment: @ChristianMark problem appears on Apache 2.4 and IIS 8. Tried PHP 5.3, 5.5 and 5.6.

Comment: @ChristianMark yes, I believe so.

Comment: what directory your PHP located?.